# Xamarin Button border issue

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make an app using Xamarin.forms. The problem is that in Android version, button border are displayed, and I would like to remove them. I tried `BorderColor="Transparent"` but it didn't work.

[image: Border button on Android]

Also, I've some problems with Text. In fact, I would like to have some padding between Icons and text (for example between F and Facebook). Is there a way to do that ? And how can I handle problems about the size of the text on, for example, iPhone 5 and "Fa...ook" ? I tried to put a smaller police but I guess there is a best solution ?

[image: Police on iPhone 5]

Here is my Xaml code:

```
<Grid Margin="0,20,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Text="Waka'Lokos" Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="22.5" TextColor="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="10" ContentLayout="Top" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="fb" Text="Facebook" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Image="fb.png" TextColor="#FEF4CA"/>
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="10" ContentLayout="Top" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="contact" Text="Contact" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Image="call.png" TextColor="#FEF4CA"/>
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="10" ContentLayout="Top" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="insta" Text="Insta" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Image="insta.png" TextColor="#FEF4CA"/>
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="10" ContentLayout="Top" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="chants" Text="Chants" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Image="micro.png" TextColor="#FEF4CA"/>
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="10" ContentLayout="Top" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="communaute" Text="Team" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Image="team.png" TextColor="#FEF4CA"/>
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="10" ContentLayout="Top" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="youtube" Text="Youtube" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Image="yt.png" TextColor="#FEF4CA"/>
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="10" ContentLayout="Top" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="partenaires" Text="Partner" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Image="partner.png" TextColor="#FEF4CA"/>
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="10" ContentLayout="Top" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="plans" Text="Bons Plans" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Image="money.png" TextColor="#FEF4CA"/>
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="10" ContentLayout="Top" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="agenda" Text="Agenda" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Image="agenda.png" TextColor="#FEF4CA"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For buttons that contain both text and images, I've always found it easiest to just use a stacklayout with an image and a label and then add a tap gesture to it. That way you have way more control over the positioning and scaling of the image as well as the text (and it takes care of your border problem). So something like:

**XAML:**

```
<StackLayout x:Name="buttonStack" WidthRequest="50">
    <Image Source="fb.png" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    <Label Text="Facebook" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
  ...
  TapGestureRecognizer tap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
  tap.Tapped += HandleClickEvent;

  buttonStack.GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);
}

private void HandleClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //some code here
}
```

if you want to fake a button tap animation you can try this instead. You can tweak the 250 milliseconds to something else to get the feel right:

```
private async void HandleClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await buttonStack.FadeTo(0,250);
  buttonStack.FadeTo(1,250);
  //some code here
}
```

Comment: It works very nice, all my problems disappeared ! I don't have the effect on buttons but it works.Thanks a lot

Comment: I edited the post to include a way to fake the button fade effect on tap. It's not perfect and you might like it better without it but it's worth a shot. Also, please mark the answer as "accepted" if it sufficiently solves your problem